# Import Existing users of Gitlab and Redmine to LDAP

Tags: gitlab, redmine, openldap, redmine-plugins

I'm want to use LDAP authentication for both my apps for that I have configured  it to work with Gitlab as well as with Redmine. Now I want to import all existing users of gitlab and redmine to LDAP server. 
Is there any plugin available or we have to do it manually?

Comment: There is a plugin, available at https://github.com/thorin/redmine_ldap_sync but its working in reverse order, putting users from AD to Redmine.

Comment: yea.. This one I checked :(

Comment: Hm, this one is a bit old, but it might work with your version of Redmine? https://github.com/alec80/redmine_ldap_push